# How to write a function that takes numbers as arguments in Clojure?

Tags: syntax, clojure, arguments

I wrote this in the REPL:

```
(defn subtract-10 [number]
  (- number 10))

#'user/subtract-10

=> (subtract-10 [45])
```

And got this?

ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.minus (Numbers.java:135)

Apparently [] takes a vector as an argument but I need a number. How can I do this, I just installed the Clojure plugin for Eclipse and tried to get some code running.

Comment: maybe you should read some "getting started" introductory guide, before beginning to code and asking such questions? this would be nice http://www.braveclojure.com/do-things/

Comment: Thanks for link and comment!

Answer (score 3):

`[45]` is a literal for a vector containing the single value 45. Simply remove the `[]` to get the literal 45:

```
(subtract-10 45)
```